# Show that $\limsup \frac{\epsilon_1+\cdots +\epsilon_n}{n}\geq 0$？

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $a_n$ is a sequence such that $a_n \downarrow 0$, 
 $\epsilon_n=-1$ or $1$ for all $n$, the series $\sum a_n$ diverges but the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n a_n$ converges. Is it true that $\limsup \frac{\epsilon_1+\cdots +\epsilon_n}{n}\geq 0$?

> Question history: **Originally, this question is about the assertion $\limsup \frac{\epsilon_1+\cdots +\epsilon_n}{n}=0$, which has been proved wrong by some wonderful answers.**

**Note**  **$a_n$ is non-increasing to zero here**. Some people forget this assumption.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66013/discussion-on-question-by-ice-sea-show-that-limsup-frac-epsilon-1-cdots-e). It seems to me that the comment chain served its purpose in that the missing assumption was added to the question body. If there is something else within the now relocated comments that is essential for a correct understanding of the question please explain, and flag this post. Alternatively just @-ping me, and I will undelete. I'm simply responding to a "too many comments" -flag.

Comment: @Ice sea.  The new statement is true. See below.

Answer (score 4):

The statement is **not true**. Using Michael's construction, but simplified gives:

$$\epsilon_n = \{1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1,1, \dots\}$$
$$\epsilon_n = (-1)^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}$$

After $1$, $7$, $31$, $\dots$, $2^{2k+1} - 1$ numbers we hit a maximum. This maximum is exactly:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2k} (-2)^i = \frac{1}{3}(2^{2k+1} + 1)$$

So at this maximum our $\sum e_n/n = \frac{1}{3}\dfrac{2^{2k+1} + 1}{2^{2k+1} - 1}$. So for large $n$ our $\limsup \sum e_n/n = \frac{1}{3}$.

---

$$a_n = \{\frac1{1\cdot 2^0}, \frac1{2\cdot 2^1}, \frac1{2\cdot 2^1}, \frac1{3\cdot 2^2}, \frac1{3\cdot 2^2}, \frac1{3\cdot 2^2}, \frac1{3\cdot 2^2}, \frac1{4\cdot 2^3}, \dots\}$$
$$a_n = \{\frac11, \frac1{4}, \frac14, \frac1{12}, \frac1{12}, \frac1{12}, \frac1{12}, \frac1{32}, \dots\}$$

$$a_n = \frac{1}{(\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor + 1)2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}}$$

$a_n$ is the harmonic series, with the $k$th element repeated $2^{k-1}$ times, divided by $2^{k-1}$. $\sum a_n$ diverges because the harmonic series does. Then, $\epsilon_n a_n$ is the alternating harmonic series, with the $k$th element repeated $2^{k-1}$ times, divided by $2^{k-1}$. The sum of this series converges just like the alternating harmonic series does:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_na_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{k}\cdot (-1)^{k} \cdot \frac{1}{(k + 1)2^{k}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} = \ln(2) \tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: I think it works. Do you think that $\limsup\frac{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2+\epsilon_3\cdots +\epsilon_n}{n}\geq 0$ always true ?

Comment: @Icesea That I don't know.

Comment: It seems not necessarily to open a new question. I have updated the problem accordingly and state the history of the question. You can update your answer accordingly.

Comment: Cooolest answer

Comment: @GuyFsone : I observe that you call this the “coolest answer,” yet you have maintained your downvote on the answer that inspired this one.  Your comments in that other answer are now moved to chat: In them, you incorrectly claim the limsup is 0, and you state you would not undo a downvote “till I see evidence.”  The above answer gives detailed evidence, and your "coolest answer" comment suggests that you now agree with that evidence.  Thus, I would expect you to undo the down vote and make amends.  However, I have not observed you doing this.

Answer (score 3):

With these hypotheses it is true that $\limsup (\epsilon_1 + \ldots + \epsilon_n)/n \geqslant 0.$

Let $S_n = \epsilon_1 + \ldots + \epsilon_n$.  Summing by parts , we have

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_ja_j = S_n a_n + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} S_j(a_j - a_{j+1}).$$

If $\limsup S_n/n  =-r < 0$, then there exists $N$ such that $S_n/n < -r/2$ for all $n > N$ and

$$\tag{*}\sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_ja_j < -\frac{r}{2}na_n + \sum_{j=1}^{N} S_j(a_j - a_{j+1}) - \frac{r}{2} \sum_{j=N+1}^{n-1}j(a_j - a_{j+1}) \\ = -\frac{r}{2}na_n + \sum_{j=1}^{N} S_j(a_j - a_{j+1}) - \frac{r}{2} \sum_{j=N+1}^{n-1}(ja_j - (j+1)a_{j+1}) - \frac{r}{2}\sum_{j=N+1}^{n-1}a_{j+1} \\ = \sum_{j=1}^{N} S_j(a_j - a_{j+1}) - \frac{r}{2}(N+1)a_{N+1} - \frac{r}{2}\sum_{j=N+1}^{n-1}a_{j+1}$$.

Since $\sum a_n$ diverges, the RHS of (*) diverges to $-\infty$ as $n \to \infty$ which contradicts the convergence of $\sum \epsilon_n a_n$.

Thus, $\limsup (\epsilon_1 + \ldots + \epsilon_n)/n \geqslant 0$.

We use the fact that $a_n$ decreases monotonically but the additional hypothesis that $a_n$ converges to $0$ is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

This answer just formalizes my hint from an hour ago, about one particular counter-example:

Define successive frames that double in size, i.e., frame $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ has size $2^k$.

Define binary $\epsilon_i$ that alternate over successive frames.  That is, $$\{1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...\}$$ Conclude that the running average of the $\epsilon_i$ values has a nonzero limsup.

It remains to define a nonnegative and nonincreasing $a_i$ sequence with a sum that diverges but such that $\sum_i a_i \epsilon_i$ converges.

---

This is an edit an hour later (requested so someone can undo a downvote).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66014/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-show-that-limsup-frac-epsilon-1-cdots-eps).